# PHP number abbreviator

Tags: php, function, math, exponent

Edit: Function below now does the abbreviation correctly, implemented @Asad 's solution

Hi I am currently working on a like button, I've got all the base functionality working nicely however I have started the number abbreviation code and hit a wall as I can't figure out how to make the abbreviation more precise.

I have a number, e.g. 1000, 1230, 1500, 154000, 1500000, 1000000

And I want to format them with an abbreviation. i.e.

if it's a thousand, then 1k, 1.1k, 2k, 10k, 10.5k etc...

and so on for the tens, hundreds thousands and millions, etc...

At the moment I have the following function but it's not specific enough:

```
function abreviateTotalCount($value) 
{

    $abbreviations = array(12 => 'T', 9 => 'B', 6 => 'M', 3 => 'K', 0 => '');

    foreach($abbreviations as $exponent => $abbreviation) 
    {

        if($value >= pow(10, $exponent)) 
        {

            return round(floatval($value / pow(10, $exponent))).$abbreviation;

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a pretty good solution, what do you mean by 'not specific enough'?

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code? Do it not work?

Comment: @Asad Hi, unfortunatley it only returns whole versions of the abbreviations i want. i.e. 1k, 2k, but nothing in between

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you have 1234567890, do you want to return "1.23456789B"?

Comment: @pedrosorio hi it's in the description: if it's a thousand, then 1k, 1.1k, 2k, 10k, 10.5k etc...

Comment: @Asad that won't do it as the result from the intval doesn't include the decimal

Comment: You might want to keep the old version so people who come to this later can see what the question was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep the decimal places, use floatval instead of intval:

```
return round(floatval($value / pow(10, $exponent)),1).$abbreviation;
```

gets the float representation and rounds to 1 decimal place.

Comment: That did it. Thanks, will accept the answer when it allows me

Answer (score 2):

check that project
https://github.com/gburtini/Humanize-PHP/blob/master/Humanize.php

```
php > echo HumanizePHP::intword(256,0,0);
3 hundred
php > echo HumanizePHP::intword(256,0,1);
2.6 hundred
php > echo HumanizePHP::intword(256,0,2);
2.56 hundred
```

At least you can take idea from this implementation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of intval(), use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to give you a number with the desired amount of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You can Rather Use these Solution from GITHUB
https://github.com/prezine/numb

`$numb = new numbConverter()
echo $numb->__main('1400000');
//output => 1.4M`

A Very easy to Use Solution

Comment: 7 year old question bro, also, the accepted answer is simpler than including an entire package for something so trivial, in addition, your package includes the code for several languages, which is bad practice.

Comment: Uhmm, newcomers like me could stumble on this question and want an answer, plus it contains several languages, just if you wish to use either of the available...

Comment: The point is we would want you to use the accepted answer instead, this is a little bit more of you plugging your library no? :) don't get me wrong, get involved, etc... but try to answer the question here, rather than plugging a library you've built. Such as by maybe showing the code in the library you used to acheive it, as that will form a better answer, which more people are likely to upvote ;)

Comment: Lol', Okay... Noted. Before the More people, be the one person to Upvote...
while I edit the answer to be formative rather than advertising

Answer (score 0):

If you ever wish to support 0, negative numbers and bigger numbers like Decillions you can try this one :)

```
function numberAbbreviation($number, $floating_points = 1) {

    $a = ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 't', 'q', 'Q', 's', 'S', 'o', 'n', 'd'];
    $n = intval($number);
    $i = intdiv(strlen((string) $n) - 1, 3);
    $m = isset($a[$i]) ? $a[$i] : '';
    $e = $floating_points;

    return number_format($n / (1000 ** $i), $m ? $e : 0) . $m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function than is simple to understand and is easily extended to more suffixes:

0: 0
1,000: 1 000
10,000: 10 K
10,100: 10.1 K
100,000: 100 K
101,500: 101 K

```php
function abbreviate_numbers(int $num){
        $num_len = strlen($num);
        switch($num_len){
            case 1: return $num;
            case 2: return $num;
            case 3: return $num;
            case 4: return number_format($num, 0, ".", " ");
            case 5: return intval(substr($num, 0, -2)) / 10 . " K";
            case 6: return intdiv($num, 1000) . " K";
            case 7: return intval(substr($num, 0, -5)) / 10 . " M";
            case 8: return intval(substr($num, 0, -5)) / 10 . " M";
            case 9: return intdiv($num, 1000000) . " M";
            case 10: return intval(substr($num, 0, -8)) / 10 . " B";
            case 11: return intval(substr($num, 0, -8)) / 10 . " B";
            case 12: return intdiv($num, 1000000000) . " B";
            case 13: return intval(substr($num, 0, -11)) / 10 . " T";
            case 14: return intval(substr($num, 0, -11)) / 10 . " T";
            case 15: return intdiv($num, 1000000000000) . " T";
            case 16: return intval(substr($num, 0, -14)) / 10 . " Q";
            case 17: return intval(substr($num, 0, -14)) / 10 . " Q";
            case 18: return intdiv($num, 1000000000000000) . " Q";
            default: return number_format($num, 0, ".", " ");
        }
    }
```